# Problema com success_url no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

Em **views** tenho as seguintes classes

```py
class AdicionarPessoaView(CustomCreateView):
    template_name = "cadastro/adicionar.html"
    form_class = PessoaForm
    model = Pessoa
    obj = Pessoa.objects.all().count()
    if obj > 0:
        obj = Pessoa.objects.last()
        success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro:add_pessoa_view', kwargs={'pk': obj.id})
    success_message = "Pessoa cadastrada com sucesso!"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AdicionarPessoaView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


class EditarPessoaView(CustomUpdateView):
    template_name = "cadastro/editar.html"
    form_class = PessoaForm
    model = Pessoa
    obj = Pessoa.objects.all().count()
    if obj > 0:
        obj = Pessoa.objects.last()
        success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro:editar_pessoa_view', kwargs={'pk': obj.id})

    success_message = "Pessoa editada com sucesso!"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditarPessoaView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

A minha intenção é que quando der `submit` na página de cadastro da pessoa a nova página seja a página de edição dessa pessoa. Porém da forma como estou usando, após adicionar ou editar uma pessoa, a página seguinte está abrindo com o `id` do cadastro anterior.
Por exemplo, se agora eu cadastrar uma `pessoa` com o id `12` e dar `submit` a página que deveria abrir seria `meusite.com/cadastro/editar/12` , mas está abrindo `meusite.com/cadastro/editar/11`.

Já tentei fazer o seguinte: Ao invés de utilizar a variável `sucess_url`, utilizei essa função nas duas classes:

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('cadastro:editar_pessoa_view', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs('pk')})
```

Porém, ao dar `submit` na página eu recebo esse erro:

```
TypeError at /cadastro/editar/12/
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'None' not found. 'None' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)
```

Qual a forma correta para que a próxima página seja a página de edição do objeto que estou adicionando/editando?

**EDIT**

Fazendo alguns testes percebi que a função `get_success_url(self)` não está "funcionando", pois quando utilizo da maneira abaixo, com a variável `success_url`, ao editar uma pessoa e dar `submit` sou redirecionado a página para um novo cadastro.

```py
class EditarPessoaView(CustomUpdateView):
    template_name = "cadastro/editar.html"
    form_class = PessoaForm
    model = Pessoa
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro:adicionar_pessoa_view')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditarPessoaView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Mas ao utilizar a função:

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('cadastro:adicionar_pessoa_view')
```

recebo o mesmo erro:

```
TypeError at /cadastro/editar/12/
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'None' not found. 'None' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)
```

O que está errado para que a função `get_success_url` não esteja funcionando?